# In memory Web API integration tests mocking out controller dependencies with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, ninject, web-api-testing, ninject-2

I have a Web API 2 application I would like to add some tests hosting the server in memory. I have this configuration in my tests.

```
        public BaseServerTests()
        {
            var fake = Substitute.For<IFooService>();

            _server = TestServer.Create(app =>
            {
                var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

                var container = new StandardKernel();
                container.Bind<IFooService>().ToConstant(fake);

                configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container);

                WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);
                app.UseWebApi(configuration);
            });

            _client = _server.HttpClient;
        }
```

The controller has only one constractor like this.

```
        public FooController(IFooService fooSrv)
        {
            _fooSrv = fooSrv;
        }
```

The Ninject configuration in the Web Api looks like this.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }
```

I am getting the following error.

**Ninject.ActivationException: 'Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from ModelValidatorProvider to NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.**

Is this the correct way of setting up the fake dependencies with Ninject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it totally wrong. I got it working now. I had to install the package Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinSelfHost.

```
        public BaseServerTests()
        {
            var fake = Substitute.For<ISomeService>();
            fake.SomeCall().Returns("this is totally fake");

            _server = TestServer.Create(app =>
            {
                var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
                var container = new StandardKernel();

                container.Bind<ISomeService>().ToConstant(fake);
                WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);

                app.UseNinject(() => container);
                app.UseNinjectWebApi(configuration);
            });

            _client = _server.HttpClient;
        }
```